# pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

This is not the first question based on this error, I know, and I have checked what I can, but still do not understand the problem.

Below is the error message.

> [Sun Jul 07 11:13:37.482061 2019] [core:crit] [pid 11261] (1)Operation not permitted: [client ::1:50913] AH00529: /Users/jokerham/Documents/Workspace/web/Nanitelink/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/Users/jokerham/Documents/Workspace/web/Nanitelink/www/' is executable

These are the things that I checked.

```
ls -al /
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  admin   192 10 26  2018 Users

ls -ale@ /Users
drwxr-xr-x+ 57 jokerham  staff  1824  7  4 23:10 jokerham
0: group:everyone deny delete

ls -ale@ /Users/jokerham
drwxr-xr-x+  29 jokerham  staff      928  3 24 18:03 Documents
0: group:everyone deny delete

ls -ale@ /Users/jokerham/Documents
drwxr-xr-x  11 jokerham  staff      352  6 21 20:44 Workspace

ls -ale@ /Users/jokerham/Documents/Workspace
drwxr-xr-x   6 jokerham  staff    192  7  4 22:51 web

ls -ale@ /Users/jokerham/Documents/Workspace/web
drwxr-xr-x   9 jokerham  staff   288  7  5 07:50 Nanitelink

ls -ale@ /Users/jokerham/Documents/Workspace/web/Nanitelink
drwxr-xr-x   6 jokerham  admin    192  6 28 07:17 www

ls -ale@ /Users/jokerham/Documents/Workspace/web/Nanitelink/www
-rw-r--r--  1 jokerham  admin   173  6 21 21:38 .htaccess
```

As seen above result, web root folder 'www' is readable & executable by anyone and .htaccess is readable by anyone. Why I am I still getting the error?

Comment: I even tried to give chmod 777 to root and .htaccess, but the error was not resolved.